# Mysql Search in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name **`tbl_marketing`** contain many column

**db_id,db_customer,db_brand,db_client....**

Another table name `tbl_phonecall` contain many column and linked with `tbl_marketing` in `db_mid` this contain the **id** of `tbl_marketing`

**db_id,db_subject,db_due,db_nextdate,db_mid**

know i create a search form this search form should do a search on all field on tbl_marketing and on db_due and db_nextdate in tbl_phonecall when the user do his search the result should like this

**Customer brand client due nextdate** 
the customer brand and client from `tbl_marketing` and the rest from `tbl_phonecall`

for that search i use this `php` code

```
$q = array();  
    $sql = "";
     if(isset($_POST['txt_name']) && !empty($_POST['txt_name'])){  
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_name']); 
    $q[] = "tbl_marketing.db_customer='".$name."' ";      
    }
    if(isset($_POST['txt_client']) && !empty($_POST['txt_client'])){  
    $client = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_client']); 
    $q[] = "tbl_marketing.db_client='".$client."' ";      
    }
    if(isset($_POST['txt_brand']) && !empty($_POST['txt_brand'])){  
    $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_brand']); 
    $q[] = "tbl_marketing.db_brand='".$brand."' ";      
    }
    if(isset($_POST['txt_dateofcalling']) && !empty($_POST['txt_dateofcalling'])){  
    $dateofcalling= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_dateofcalling']);
    $searchdateofcalling=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($dateofcalling));    
    $q[] = "DATE(tbl_phonecall.db_due)='".$searchdateofcalling."' ";      
    }
     if(isset($_POST['txt_nextdate']) && !empty($_POST['txt_nextdate'])){  
    $nextdate= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['txt_nextdate']);
    $searchnextdate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($nextdate));       
    $q[] = "DATE(tbl_phonecall.db_nextdate)='".$searchnextdate."' ";      
    }
    $first = true; 
    foreach($q as $qu){  
        if($first){  
        $sql .= " where ".$qu;      
        $first = false;  
        }else{  
        $sql .= " and ".$qu;          
        } 
    } 
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select tbl_marketing.*,tbl_phonecall.* from tbl_marketing,tbl_phonecall {$sql}")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

but this query repeat the value

How can i solve that problem and have a result like i post before

Comment: echo($sql) before select query and what is shown?

Comment: @affaz select tbl_marketing.*,tbl_phonecall.* from tbl_marketing,tbl_phonecall where DATE(tbl_phonecall.db_due)='2017-02-01 00:00:00'

Comment: did u give echo before or after select?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed the join condition

```
where tbl_marketing.db_id = tbl_phonecall.db_mid
```

In case you want to return records from tbl_marketing even if no matching records exist in tbl_phonecall table, use left join in your query

```
select tbl_marketing.*,tbl_phonecall.* 
from tbl_marketing left join tbl_phonecall 
on tbl_marketing.id = tbl_phonecall.mid 
where ....<<where conditions here>>
```

Comment: This only work if i search on due and next date on tbl_phonecal but if i search on a field in tbl_marketing didn't work give me no result

Comment: Probably tbl_phonecal doesnt have records matching for that id. Use left join in your query 
 select tbl_marketing.*,tbl_phonecall.* 
 from tbl_marketing left join tbl_phonecall
 on tbl_marketing.id = tbl_phonecall.mid
 where ....<<where conditions here>>